# Check if color contains alpha channel with SASS

Tags: sass

I need to check if a color contains alpha channel with SASS.

I can't check that with `alpha` and `opacity` functions:

```
alpha(rgba(210, 225, 221, 1)); // returns 1
alpha(#d2e1dd); // also returns 1
```

What I want is something like that:

```
has-alpha(rgba(210, 225, 221, 1)); // true
has-alpha(#d2e1dd); // false
```

Comment: I have a solution but it requires to put the colors between quotes, would it be a problem for your use cases?

Comment: No, it's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naive way to do it:

```
@function has-alpha($color) {
   @return if(str-index($color, "rgba"), true, false);
}

has-alpha('rgba(210, 225, 221, 1)') // true
has-alpha('#d2e1dd'); // false
```

The `has-alpha` function will just check if `$color` contains `rgba` with `str-index` and then return `true` or `false`. The function requires a string parameter to work so you need to send the colors between quotes.

Note that if you also want to detect when a [hex color has alpha channel](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation) (such as `#d2e1ddff`), you need to change the function to something like:

```
@function has-alpha($color) {
  @if str-index($color, "rgba") {
    @return true;
  } @else if str-index($color, "#") and str-length($color) == 9 {
    @return true;
  } @else {
    @return false;
  }
}
```

Hex with alpha channel have 8 digits but here the `str-length` also count the `#`, so the condition check if it has 9 characters instead of 8.

You can also write it in a more concise manner:

```
@function has-alpha($color) {
  $hasAlpha: str-index($color, "rgba") or (str-index($color, "#") and str-length($color) == 9);
  @return if($hasAlpha, true, false);
}
```